# align y-axis labels using charts.js

Tags: charts, chart.js

im using [charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) to display a combined chart. I want to know if its possible to align all the y-axis left, i havent found an answer for this in the docs.

My chart labels are looking like this:

[image: actual label alignment]

and i want it to look aligned like:

[image: desired alignment]

is there a way to do this?